# How to create User Task only once a day

Tags: camunda

We want to collect data during the day and create an User Task once a day. How can that be done with camunda? Is there a possibility to use process variables or do we need to access our own database and mark the corresponding items as processed (as soon as we create the daily user task)?

Do we need to create these user tasks programmatically? (We are using embedded Spring Boot Camunda instance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One very good option would be to use a Timer Start Event per the documentation here: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.10/reference/bpmn20/events/timer-events/#timer-start-event.

It seems that you may want to use that in conjunction with a Timer Intermediate Catching Event (https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.10/reference/bpmn20/events/timer-events/#timer-intermediate-catching-event) in something like the following manner:

- Start a process instance at a specific time in the morning with the Timer Start Event. Perhaps 6:30AM in your local time zone?
- Execute certain steps to gather data, perhaps through external service invocations, etc.
- At a specific time (in the afternoon?), create the User Task and present the data. The User Task could follow the Timer Intermediate Catching Event noted above.

I hope this helps!